# The subset of a set of vectors such the this subset has the points at most extreme values for all dimentions

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

Condiser $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

We can define some the set of per axis outermost points, on a per axis:

$$Out(X) = \{ x \mid x \in X \: \wedge \: (\exists i\in[1,n], x_i=\underset{y\in X}{argmax\:}{y_i} \:\:\vee\:\: x_i=\underset{y\in X}{argmin\:}{y_i}) \}$$

where $x_i$ is the ith element of the vector $x$

#### Properties

Some properties I note:

- If I understand convex hulls correctly, then it is readily apparent that:

$$Out(X) \subseteq Conv(X)$$

- but not nesciaryly a subset of the convex hull vertices as @Chris pointed out.

  - The If there are no ties, and there each point is only an extreme for one dimension, then size of $Out(X) = 2n$.

    - but can be smaller, if some points are at extremes on multiple indexes for example: $$Out(\{(2,2,3),(0,0,0),(0,1,2),(0,1,1),(1,0,1)(-1,-1,-1)\}=\{(2,2,3),(-1,-1,-1)\}$$
    - or larger, if there are ties, as @Chris pointed out also, eg:
      $$Out(\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)\})=\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)\}$$

Is there a name for this operation?

Comment: I'm not sure if the definition is stated the way you want. What is $Out(\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)\})$ meant to be?

Comment: This is not exactly a name for this operation, but a term you might look up is "bounding box". (Happens to fit well with your user name :-)

Comment: @Chris $Out(\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)\})=\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)\}$ as all points lay on the 2nd dimensional boundary

Comment: Got it, but then, your two properties don't hold.

Comment: True they don't, let me fix them